# Adding Apple Mapkit to Openlayers as a base map

Tags: leaflet, maps, mapkit, openlayers, apple-maps

Is there a possible way to add Mapkit as a base layer to OpenLayers or is there any library like [Leaflet.MapkitMutant](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.MapkitMutant) for Openlayers.

I've seen Google maps ([ol3-googl e-maps](https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps)) integration for Openlayers but couldn't find similar library for Apple's Mapkit

Comment: Look into https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.MapkitMutant

Comment: I already looked at that library but before trying to convert it for OpenLayers, I wanted to ask is there another solution. If there is a similar library and I've missed it, this would be the waste of time to convert it probably, because i am not experienced over OpenLayers and i am not sure how to extend this library properly. And on the other hand, i am looking into OpenLayers library to how to extend it, in case i can't find any other solution